# MediaPlayer prepareAsync() method throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use MediaPlayer to stream music from a web-server, it looks like this:

```
try {
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource(audioUrl);
                player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
                player.prepareAsync();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("PLAY", "can't play it");
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
```

Unfortinatelly `prepareAsync()` always throws IllegalStateException when debugging, so I never get to the `onPrepared()` method. I tried to use `prepare()` instead of `prepareAsync()`, but it throws IOException. I looked up this problem, but everything I could find was to add 
`android.permission.INTERNET` to the manifest or to invoke `start()` from `setOnPrepareListener` (which I've already done).

The weirdest thing is that my app works correctly when it's running inspite of the fact that I never invoke start() method during debugging. Does anyone know what this means?

EDIT 1:
Here is what I got using logcat on Debug level (I hope that's what you meant):

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2292K, 18% free 11063K/13392K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 1
D/dalvikvm:   JDWP invocation returning with exceptObj=0x43d24770 (Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;)
E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 1
D/dalvikvm:   JDWP invocation returning with exceptObj=0x43af0d50 (Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;)
E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 4
03-05 21:03:20.316 5459-5459/com.example.vkmusic D/dalvikvm:   JDWP invocation returning with exceptObj=0x43dee6c0 (Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;)
E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 8
```

EDIT 2: Alright, it turned out that exceptions are thrown during debugging only if I put a method into Watches otherwise it works without any exceptions. For example if I put `player.setDataSource(audioUrl)` there, it throws Exception when it reach the same line in the code. Totally the same thing happens to `player.prepareAsync()` and now I'm totally confused. Why is that happening?

Comment: Add your LogCat please

Comment: Have you gave the read external permission in manifeast.xml ?

Comment: @Aakash Mangukiya, if you meant android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE then yes, but it doesn't help

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: Alright, I found out what the problem was. When I call methods from Watches, it changed state of the MediaPlayer object, so when compilator is trying to call this method it's not necessarelly because it already had been executed from Watches. It's like if I call some method 2 times in a line.